# TypeError in pybullet code: an integer is required (got type list)

Tags: python, list, pybullet

```
import pybullet as p
import pybullet_data
import time

obstacles_coor=[[-5,10,2.5],[2,10,2.5],[10,10,2.5],[0,5,2.5],[-10,-5,2.5]]

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)
p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
p.loadURDF('plane.urdf', [0,0,0])

p.setGravity(0,0,-10)

for obs in obstacles_coor:
    p.loadURDF("cube.urdf",obs,globalScaling=0.5)
    p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
obstacles_coor.pop()
# obs = p.loadURDF("cube.urdf", globalScaling=0.5)
cube=p.loadURDF("cube.urdf", [0,0,1])

def contactPoints():
        #obs is a list>
      contacts = p.getContactPoints(bodyA=cube, bodyB=obs)
      for contact in contacts:
          link_index = contact[2]
          if link_index >= 2:
                #   p.removeBody(obstacles_coor[0])
                del(obstacles_coor[0])

for i in range(10000):
    p.stepSimulation()
    contactPoints()
    time.sleep(1./240.)
```

the error jumps at the line:

```
contacts = p.getContactPoints(bodyA=cube, bodyB=obs)
```

With this error log:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
an integer is required (got type list)
  File "C:\Users\AisyahJeff\niche_evo_single_species\old_model\test.py", line 58, in contactPoints
    contacts = p.getContactPoints(bodyA=cube, bodyB=obs)
  File "C:\Users\AisyahJeff\niche_evo_single_species\old_model\test.py", line 69, in <module>
    contactPoints()
```

I am thinking it is python type of error instead of `pybullet`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that have this problem, my friend gave me a solution:

```
import pybullet as p
import pybullet_data
import time

obstacles_coor=[[-5,10,2.5],[2,10,2.5],[10,10,2.5],[0,5,2.5],[-10,-5,2.5]]

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)
p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
p.loadURDF('plane.urdf', [0,0,0])

cube=p.loadURDF("cube.urdf", [0,0,1])

obstacles_list=[]
for obs in obstacles_coor:
        obstacles_list.append(p.loadURDF("cube.urdf",obs,globalScaling=0.5))

p.setGravity(0,0,-10)


def contactPoints():
      #obs is a list> 
      for obs_idx in obstacles_list:
        contacts = p.getContactPoints(bodyA=cube, bodyB=obs_idx)
        for contact in contacts:
            link_index = contact[2]
            if link_index >= 2:
                  #del(obstacles_coor.pop(0))
                p.removeBody(obstacles_coor.pop(0))


for i in range(10000):
    p.stepSimulation()
    contactPoints()
    time.sleep(1./240.)
```

obstacles_coor or obs in this context is a list, not an int. Therefore it is not suitable for the p.getContactPoints argument. So, recognize it as index 'idx' in the argument so it can be an int.